# How to fix this "for each not applicable to type'package name' "?

Tags: java, mysql, iterable

"I'm trying to display the data in my child item for FAQ screen but I'm getting  the error" I am getting an error about IDNA info and mcontext

MainActivity

```
        for (Feed feed : Utils.loadFeeds(this.getApplicationContext())) {
            mExpandableView.addView(new HeadingView(mContext, feed.getHeading()));
            for (Info info : feed.getInfoList()) {
                mExpandableView.addView(new InfoView(mContext, info));
            }
        }*/
//        setLoadMoreListener(mExpandableView);
    }

    private void setLoadMoreListener(ExpandablePlaceHolderView expandableView)  {
        mOnScrollListener =
                new PlaceHolderView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        ExpandablePlaceHolderView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                        if(layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
                            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
                            int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            int lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!mIsLoadingMore
                                    && !mNoMoreToLoad
                                    && totalItemCount > 0
                                    && totalItemCount == lastVisibleItem + 1) {
                                mIsLoadingMore = true;
                                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                                        .post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        // do api call to fetch data

                                        // example of loading from file:
                                        for(Feed feed : Utils.loadFeeds(getApplicationContext())){
                                            mExpandableView.addView(new HeadingView(mContext, feed.getHeading()));
                                            //for (Map.Entry<String, List<Treet>> entry : treetsByAuthor.entrySet()){
                                            for(Info info : feed.getInfoList()) {
                                                mExpandableView.addView(new InfoView(mContext, info));
                                            }
                                        }
                                        mIsLoadingMore = false;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
        expandableView.addOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
    }
}

for(Feed feed : Utils.loadFeeds(getApplicationContext())){
                                            mExpandableView.addView(new HeadingView(mContext, feed.getHeading()));
                                            //for (Map.Entry<String, List<Treet>> entry : treetsByAuthor.entrySet()){
                                            for(Info info : feed.getInfoList()) {
                                                mExpandableView.addView(new InfoView(mContext, info));
                                            }
                                        }
                                        mIsLoadingMore = false;
                                    }
                                });
```

error
error: for-each not applicable to expression type
required: array or java.lang.Iterable
found:    Info

Comment: You have several enhanced `for` loops in your code, which one of them throws the error? I guess it's `for(Info info : feed.getInfoList())`, because the error message states `... found: Info`. What does `feed.getInfoList()` return? Is it an array or an `Iterable` or just a single `Info`?

Comment: Actually I was getting IDNA.info error at first later on clearing the errors I got this feed.getInfoList. It is an array

Comment: Can you tell which line throws the error?

Comment: this line for(Info info : feed.getInfoList())

Comment: Then `feed.getInfoList()` does not return an array or an `Iterable`... Are you sure the method signature has an `Info[]` and not just an `Info`?

Comment: Ok, problem solved i dint give Info[] ... Thank you so much.